# Difference between two ways of accessing a row's cells

Tags: vba, excel

What's the difference between accessing a row's cells these ways:

```
   Sub test6()
        Dim wRange As Range
        Set wRange = Range("B3:P10")
        For Each aRow In wRange.Rows
            'need to get this row's second column (B)
            Cells(aRow.Row, 4).value = aRow.Cells(1, 2).Address
            Cells(aRow.Row, 5).value = Cells(aRow.Row, 2).Address
        Next
    End Sub
```

I get weird results, depending on the range. Besides I have a more complex program that also gives different results when using these two methods.

Answer (score 5):

I changed your procedure a bit and added the output of `Debug.Print` as comment to better explain why this is an expected result:

```
Option Explicit 'in the first line of your modules: Ensures you need to declare all variables

Sub test6()
    Dim wRange As Range, aRow As Variant
    Set wRange = Range("B3:P10")

    For Each aRow In wRange.Rows
                                                ' Outputs of the first loop run:
        Debug.Print aRow.Address                ' $B$3:$P$3
        Debug.Print aRow.Cells(1, 2).Address    ' $C$3
        Debug.Print Cells(aRow.Row, 2).Address  ' $B$3
    Next
End Sub
```

**Explanationː**
`aRow` is a sub range (`$B$3:$P$3`) out of the original range `B3:P10` containing only one row (but not an entire row of the worksheet as you assume) so `aRow.Cells(1, 2)` refers to column 2 relative to `aRow` which is `C` because the range is starting with `B` not with `A`.

`Cells(aRow.Row, 2)` is exactly the same as writing `ActiveSheet.Cells(aRow.Row, 2)` and refers to column 2 relative to the `ActiveSheet` which is `B` because the range of the sheet is starting at `A`.

`aRow.EntireRow.Cells(1, 2).Address` would be the same as `Cells(aRow.Row, 2).Address` because now we refer to the entire row starting at column `A`.

**Side note:**
I recommend not to assume the worksheet and fully qualify your cells/ranges so you always see to which range the cells are relative to.

Answer (score 1):

Your result isn't weird, because `aRow.Cells().Address` returns an address, relative  to column B, since first column of `wRange` is B too.

So in your case you need this line instead:

```
        ...
        'need to get this row's second column (B)
        Cells(AROW.Row, 4).Value = AROW.Cells(1, 1).Address
                                                '^ relative index
        ...
```

And when you use this property without an object qualifier (simply `Cells()`) - this gives your a result relative to entire active worksheet!

[The RowIndex and ColumnIndex arguments are relative offsets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841096.aspx#Anchor_1).

Answer (score 0):

Cells(aRow.Row, 4) refers to the cells of the ActiveSheet. aRow.Cells(1, 2) refers to a cell in teh aRow range.